# Mysql Display four(4) digit numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, select, digits

In Mysql I want to display numbers using 4 digit patterns.
example :

```
select 1    => result : 0001
select 2    => result : 0002
select 25   => result : 0025
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`lpad`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function to pad zeroes to the left of the result:

```
SELECT LPAD(mycol, 4, '0')
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using lpad() function

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e7f998f45461db42ca597a0563fde48)

```
SELECT LPAD(columnanme, 4,'0');
```

Output:

```
LPAD('11', 4,'0')
0011
```